# Prevent button to execute if field is empty and "status" still in the database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have form with some field in it and a button to be execute. What I want to do is, when any of field is empty, the button cannot be executed. That means, I cannot proceed the button procees when the field is not completed.

How can I prevent the button to be execute if field empty? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

#### **Update Question**

I will add some more information to my problem. For now, I'm try to prevent using

```
If doc.PStatus(0) = "Lock" Then
    Msgbox "Complete PC Inspection first!"
    Exit Sub
Else
```

to check if there is status LOCK then I cannot execute the button. If I made some changes to the document and there still LOCK status, I cannot proceed the button. I will prompt message "Complete PC Inspection first!" and exit sub. I thought I succeed but not. I try two condition:

1. I try made changes to document but not start with first document in the view. (Its ok and I cannot proceed to execute process)
2. I try made changes to the first document only in the view, then I can execute the button (where supposedly I cannot because there still "LOCK" status).

I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605093/9688943) from my previous question but the problem still occurred. The problem occurred only when I made changes to my very first document in view. But there is no problem if I made changes to other document other than first document. I hope you understand the question. I will add additional code if you guys need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this button is in a view, your code needs to be in a loop that gets each document and separately checks the values of the field in each document.

Comment: My button in a form, and my form display in the view. Is it considered button in view?