# Why is my button in form not worked properly

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Before this I already asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56829458/9688943) but I still did not get it fixed. I try every possible way but still cannot fix the problem.

I will try to explain again. Basically I have list of document with status "Active". So my button is on "Batch" view. My button process start with check all documents in "Computer" view whether there is "Lock" status. If any document have "Lock" status then exit sub, else continue process. Process continue is first set batch no. Then create copy document in "Computer". Copy document will have status "Draft" and current document will replaceitemvalue to "Lock". This process will continue for all document.

So below here my lotusscript button.

```
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set uiview = ws.CurrentView

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set dialogDoc = uidoc.Document
Set view = db.GetView("Computer")

Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.PStatus(0) = "Lock" Then
        Msgbox "Complete PC Inspection first!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        answer% = Messagebox("Do you confirm?")
        If Not answer% = 6 Then
            Msgbox("Process Incomplete")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            dialogDoc.Form = "BatchInfo"
            Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SaveOptions", "1")
            Call uidoc.Save
            While Not (doc Is Nothing)
                If doc.PStatus(0) = "Active" Then

            '-----create new copy document-----'
                    Set newdoc = doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
                    newdoc.PBatchNo = dialogDoc.BBatchNo(0)
                    newdoc.PStatus = "Draft"
                    Call newdoc.Save(True, False)

                    doc.PStatus = "Lock"
                    Call doc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
                    Call doc.save(True,False)
                End If
                Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
            Wend
            Messagebox("Process completed.")
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
Wend
```

So right now all documents in "Computer" will have status "Lock", so when I click again the button, it should straight exit sub.

**First testing**:
So right now, I will change status of any document in "Computer" list from "Lock" become "Active". Any document except first document. Then I will return "Batch" view and CLICK button, it show msgbox "Complete PC Inspection first!". It means there is no problem

**Second testing**:
So now, I try second testing. This testing is similar with first testing but for this testing, I will change status of document for very "First Document" in "Computer" view. Then I return back to "Batch" view and CLICK button, it ignore message and go to line 14 which is "answer% = Messagebox("Do you confirm?")". It not supposed to skip to this line because in "Computer" view, there are still document with "Lock" status.

I have try any possible way but I cannot succeed. Anyone can help with my problem? I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Did you refresh the view between your tests ? alternative you could add the call view.refresh() after your set view=

Comment: No, I do not refresh the view. and I already try insert call view.refresh() but it still the same.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. You have 2 While loops yet you use one view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your description of what you are trying to do, I think you need toclose your first While..Wend loop before getting to your first Else

```
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set uiview = ws.CurrentView

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set dialogDoc = uidoc.Document
Set view = db.GetView("Computer")

'First run through the loop checks if ANY doc has PStatus = "Lock"
Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If doc.PStatus(0) = "Lock" Then
        Msgbox "Complete PC Inspection first!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set doc = view.getNextDocument(doc) 'add (doc)
Wend

'Not sure what this is all about, but I'll leave it in
answer% = Messagebox("Do you confirm?")
If Not answer% = 6 
    Msgbox("Process Incomplete")
    Exit Sub
Else
    'I've no idea what the next three lines are for, but I'll leave them alone
    dialogDoc.Form = "BatchInfo"
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SaveOptions", "1")
    Call uidoc.Save

    'Loop through the view again, creating copies and setting status to Lock
    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument 'Add this line
    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        If doc.PStatus(0) = "Active" Then

            '-----create new copy document-----'
            Set newdoc = doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
            newdoc.PBatchNo = dialogDoc.BBatchNo(0)
            newdoc.PStatus = "Draft"
            Call newdoc.Save(True, False)

            doc.PStatus = "Lock"
            Call doc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
            Call doc.save(True,False)
        End If
        Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
     Wend
End If
Messagebox("Process completed.")
```

I hope that helps. I think your problem was the you thought you were going through the whole view looking for a document with PStatus = "Lock", but because your Wend was right at the end of the code, and there wasn't a view.getnextdocument(doc), it simply wasn't happening.

Comment: Instead of looping through all documents, it's much easier/faster to do a simple lookup of a Lock document in some lookup view. Plus there are other inconsistencies, as you correctly noted.

Comment: Hi @PhilMJones , you really help me solve the problem. I succeded solve it after for long time. I will add few thing missing in your code and it work like charm. :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @D.Bugger , I already try do simple lookup but still have problem. Maybe I implemented it in wrong way. I will try using lookup again later. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: @Reinhaa Thanks for the edit - I hadn't tested the code in Designer, so bugs were inevitable :)

Comment: Sure @PhilMJones and thank you for your answer. Next time I will try carefully using While wend.